# Не убирается блок при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, css

На сайте есть сторонний виджет или что то вроде этого, тема wp, нужно убрать блок но стилями не получается так как файл сторонний я так понимаю, пытаюсь убрать путем написания скрипта но тоже не получается, вот скрипт, может ошибка где то?

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
            function blockHide() {
                var hide1 = document.getElementByID(znDemosPanel);
                hide1.style.display = 'none';
            }
            window.onload = blockHide;
        </script>
```

ReferenceError: znDemosPanel is not defined - ошибка из консоли

Answer (score 1):

`getElementByID` пишется `getElementById`

```js
            function blockHide() {
                var hide1 = document.getElementById('znDemosPanel');
                hide1.style.display = 'none';
            }
            window.onload = blockHide;
```

```html
<div id="znDemosPanel">Test</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не работает даже с правильным написанием

Comment: `znDemosPanel` это я так понимаю ID елемента и он пишется `.getElementById('znDemosPanel')`

Comment: TypeError: hide1 is null - сейчас консоль выдает, подозреваю что не видет js этот ID, просто на главной странице нету этого блока znDemosPanel. И вообще он подключен каким образом я не понимаю но надо его убрать, в стилях темы если ему display:none поставить то тоже не работает

Comment: https://artbasket.store/ - вот ссылка для наглядности, там слева you get 60+ demo - вот его и надо скрыть

Comment: То есть справа.

Comment: ну это уже вам надо искать где у вас генерирует ваш блок, гадание на "коде"  - тяжело.

Comment: @ilyaaa521 На странице по [ссылке](https://artbasket.store/) вы пытаетесь отобразить запрашиваемый демо-контент. Сам контент находится внутри iframe и повлиять на него вы не сможете, ни стилями, ни скриптом. Точнее, при загрузке данных можно отфильтровать запрашиваемый контент, но, не понятно, каким способом вы все это делаете, а значит и советов никто не даст дельных.